# Efficient CSV Row Reduction JS

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a huge csv that I'm trying to filter based on user input. It looks something like this:

```
from,phone_number,from_date
Seattle,123,6/15/15
Omaha,321,6/14/15
```

I have a function that is supposed to take user input and then match only the rows that meet that criteria.

```
var lst = []
var lst2 = []
var lst3 = []

function mapper() {
var dateu = document.getElementById("userInputdate").value;
var cityu = document.getElementById("userInputcity").value;
var numberu = document.getElementById("userInputnumber").value;

d3.csv("some.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    city: d.from,
    number: d.phone_number,
    date: d.from_date
  };
}, function(error, rows) {
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    lst.push(rows);
if (dateu.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
        if (lst[i].date === dateu) {
            lst.push(rows[i]);
            console.log(rows[i]);
        }
    }
    if (cityu.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
            if (lst[i].city === cityu) {
                lst2.push(lst[i]);
                console.log(lst2);
            }
        }
        if (numberu.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < lst2.length; i++) {
                if (lst[i].number === numberu) {
                    lst3.push(lst2[i]);
                    console.log(lst3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}})};
```

The matching and passing works, but the the problem is the user doesn't necessarily have to enter all the fields. For example they might only input data into the "city_u" variable and unfortunately the city matching (second if statement) currently relies on the array from the previous if statement.

Im looking for a good way to get each if statement the most filtered version of the data that it can receive. So the second and third if statements will run regardless of whether or not the previous ones have.

Oh I almost forgot to mention, I also need to be able to write this final array to a csv. Importantly this is not going to be hosted online immediately. The csv should just write to the same folder the files are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you want to filter based on these three variables ,, maybe this function helps you

```
function apply_filters(data, dateu,cityu,numberu){
    if(dateu) { 
        data = data.filter(function(item){return item.date == dateu;});
    };
    if(cityu){
        data = data.filter(function(item){return item.city == cityu;});
    } 
    if(numberu){
        data = data.filter(function(item){return item.number == numberu;});
    }
    return data;
}
```

so you will need to pass the data array to it and the three filters as params 
you can read about **filter** function from here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: This is so perfect, it keeps a single array intact. This is exactly what I was stuck on! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach, it includes a parser for the data. I don't like the way the property names are hard coded in the data, they should be passed in or stored based on what the parser finds:

```
var data = 'from,phone_number,from_date' +
           '\nSeattle,123,7/14/15' +
           '\nSeattle,456,7/15/15' +
           '\nSeattle,789,7/15/15' +
           '\nOmaha,456,6/14/15';

// Parse data, using first row as field names
function parseData(data) {

  data = data.split('\n');
  var labels = data.shift().split(',');

  return data.map(function(record) {
    var obj = {};
    var b = record.split(',');
    labels.forEach(function(label,i){obj[label] = b[i] || ''}); 
    return obj;
  });
}

// Filter data based on provided values for 
function apply_filters(data, dateu, cityu, numberu){

  // Return undefined if no criteria provided
  if (!data || (!dateu && !cityu && !numberu)) return;

  // Arguments are in different order to csv data
  var props  = ['from_date','from','phone_number'],
      args   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.shift();

  // Filter data on supplied arguments
  return data.filter(function(rec){
    return args.every(function(arg, i){
      return !arg || arg == rec[props[i]];
    }); 
  });
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(apply_filters(parseData(data),null,null,'456')) );
```

It can be reduced to less code, but readability suffers. If no arguments are provided, it returns *undefined*, but could just as easily return a copy of *data*.